# Console.Log Not Being Called Inside React Constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to add a component to a default .NET Core MVC with React project. I believe I have everything wired up to mirror the existing "Fetch Data" component, but it doesn't seem like it's actually being called (but the link to the component in my navbar does move to a new page).

The component itself...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class TestComponent extends Component {
    static displayName = TestComponent.name;

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("WHO NOW?");
        this.state = { message: '', loading: true, promise: null };

        this.state.promise = fetch('api/SampleData/ManyHotDogs');

        console.log(this.state.promise);
    }

    static renderForecastsTable (message) {
        return (
            <h1>
                Current Message: {message}
            </h1>
        );
    }

    render () {
        let contents = this.state.loading

            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : TestComponent.renderForecastsTable(this.state.message);

        return (

            <div>
                <h1>Weather forecast</h1>
                <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>
                {contents}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { FetchData } from './components/FetchData';
import { Counter } from './components/Counter';
import { TestComponent } from './components/TestComponent';

export default class App extends Component {
  static displayName = App.name;

  render () {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/counter' component={Counter} />
        <Route path='/fetch-data' component={FetchData} />
        <Route path='/test-controller' component={TestComponent} />
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}
```

That console.log("Who now") is never called when I inspect, and the page remains totally blank. I can't find a key difference between this and the functioning components, and google has not been much help either. Any ideas what is missing?

***Edit***

While troubleshooting this, I ended up creating a dependency nightmare that broke the app. Since I'm only using the app to explore React, I nuked it and started over--and on the second attempt I have not been able to reproduce the not-rendering issue.

Comment: I think you need "export default" keyword  in your component TestComponent i.ie:
export default class TestComponent extends Component

Comment: @KenanBalija Adding that (which doesn't match any of the functioning example components from the project template) broke the binding with App.js

Answer (score 2):

It is advisable to use componentDidMount to make the call to the REST API with the fetch or axios.

```
class TestComponent extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    state = {promise: ''}
  }
  async componentDidMount () {
    let promise = await fetch ('api / SampleData / ManyHotDogs');
    this.setState ({promise});
    console.log (promise);
  }
  render(){
    return(
        <div>{this.state.promise}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great callout, but I'm doing something *else* wrong still, since after making this change the component still doesn't do anything.

Comment: Don't render anything ? Can u explain a little more ? Any error log in your console ?

Comment: That's the weird part--I didn't get an error in the console. It was almost like my component was just not being spun up in the first place and I couldn't see why. I ended up creating a problem with the dependencies that made it impossible to get the app to run at all, so I ended up nuking it and starting over--which has been much more successful.