# console.log not being called inside react-native constructor

Tags: javascript, react-native, initialization

I'm really new to react and react-native and I'm having a problem with this really simple code below.
The code below is on a minimal react native app.
It renders the content inside the render method, but looks like it isn't executing the instructions inside the constructor, the alert box neither the log appears in console.
I need to ensure a variable is initialized just on application startup and it was my way to check it. I'm thinking about a logic using Undefined and give up on using constructor.

Some related links I found:
[constructor in React not being called upon component being instantiated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55642497/constructor-in-react-not-being-called-upon-component-being-instantiated)
[Console.Log Not Being Called Inside React Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55425117/console-log-not-being-called-inside-react-constructor)

My code:

```
class TestComponent extends Component {
  Constructor(props){
    this.super(props);
    console.log("CalingConstructorLog"); // do nothing
    Alert.alert("CalingConstructorLog"); // do nothing
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>It renders OK!</Text>
    );
  }
}
export default TestComponent;
```

Comment: `Constructor` needs to be lower case: `constructor`

Comment: It's just `super(props)`. No need for `this`.